# Get price and images of main content of defined URL with PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler

First of, let me say that I'm a Frontend engineer, with limited knowledge to PHP. I can make  simple webservices to complete my projects, but I'm not near calling myself a Backend developer. :-)

I'm making a website in my spare time, where users can enter a URL of a product and the service, made in php, returns the 5 largest images on the page, sorted by size. The largest image is, usually, the correct image. Mark this as half done.. :-)

However, now I need to get the price that match the product, not just any price on the page. A lot of webshops lists alternative or related products with prices as well, so there could be numerous instances. I could bubble up the Dom three and match the first price that's inside the same parent as the selected image. But is that the way to go?

How do I track down the main content of a page, so my image getter function is more precise, and the price is correct? As I don't know the markup, how would I recognize the main content?

As for getting prices, I tried getting all elements with indexOf price in class, which works in 90% of the time. But that gives me, as mentioned before, all prices - not THE price.

So, long story short. How do I: 
1. recognize main content of a webpage, without knowing it's markup? 
2. Or find the price that match the image selected as the right one?

Comment: Do you particularly need a code solution for this? If not, consider import.io - they offer free desktop software that looks quite good.

Comment: I'm getting sick about the administrators of this website, who closes questions for invalid reasons. This is a real question. Do you close it because I haven't pasted in any code? What is your reason? I need help with setting up a scraper/crawler... What's the problem?!

Comment: I think perhaps you've misunderstood the role of the folks below, Kenneth - a mistake I made early on when using SE sites. The users below are just your fellow users, and not administrators or moderators at all. They do however pass a reputation score threshold that allows them to cast close votes based on their understanding of the posting guidelines.

Comment: As for the question itself, I'd say it doesn't meet the guidelines. I do know it's frustrating, since _traditional_ forums essentially make every programming question on-topic, and the Stack Overflow position is that such a policy has been their downfall. Personally I wouldn't mind if design questions such as yours were on-topic, since you've clearly thought about it prior to asking (that would leave us free to close design questions where no prior effort had been made). If you like, you can always post a query to [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and raise it there.

Comment: Meantime, if you would respond to my advice about import.io, I would appreciate it. I like helping people, but a little gratitude goes a long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you're asking for help figuring out an algorithm to identify the correct price on each page.

In this case, I'd write code that gets all prices first. Then I would expand my code to add as much metadata to each identified price as possible.

Things like:

- Where in the DOM it was located,
- How far into the document it was in terms of characters
- Styling information, like font size
- Which website this was scraped from
- Location on page

Add as much information as you can think of.

Then you do some data mining. Scrape a bunch of pages. See if you can identify any patterns in the metadata. Start website-specific, and later generalize it to different sites.

Write a ranking algorithm based on the patterns you saw in the metadata. Then rank each price based on the patterns you could identify based off metadata.

Allow your users to identify when your program got it wrong, so that you can improve the algorithm.

Alternatively, automate it using Bayesian analysis on your data to make educated guesses, the same way that spam filters currently clean up spam.

Bonus points for ranking price estimates based on the standard deviation from multiple pages. Basically, look at the prices your algorithm thinks are best for *all* the pages you scraped (I assume you want to compare multiple sellers for the same product), and have it not prefer outliers, any values that are way outside the expected range.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and thourghts on the project. I will not compare prices on multiple suppliers, as the user will paste in an URL to the exact product, but everything else you suggest sounds nice.

I am, however, still a n00b and this seems like a huge task for me, so I think I will cut some corners and make a simple version of what you suggest. I really liked the thorough approach. Thumbs up!

Comment: No problem. You asked for an algorithm that is general for any web page, but you will probably get best results by writing code specific to each seller. If you go that route, remember to check if they have APIs for price checks and queries.

Comment: Cutting corners for a first version is fine. Programs almost always start out simple, and grow more complex and better over time. A good rule of thumb is to [make it work, then make it right, then make it fast](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast).